# Checking a variable is a certain value when Python script is run

Tags: python, python-3.x

When entering a password that is incorrect, I'm setting the variable `"incorrectguess" to 1`.

After the user guesses incorrectly and the variable is changed, it runs `destroyapp()`

Is there a way to setup Python to check what the value is as soon as the script is run and if it is `"1"` to run `destroyapp()` and if it is not (i.e. `"0"`) to let the program continue?

I'm guessing the best way to do this would be with a while loop but I couldn't figure out how to do this without giving the variable a value anyway, making `destroyapp()` useless.

Edit: Sorry, here's the code:

```
import time

import ctypes

if incorrectguess == ("1"):

print ("Running.")
#time.sleep(1)
print ("Running..")
#time.sleep(1)
print ("Running...")
#time.sleep(1)
print ("Running....")
#time.sleep(1)
print ("Running.....")
###
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
###
#time.sleep(3)
print ("hello you")
#time.sleep(5)
print ("have you been waiting long")
#time.sleep(9)
print ("im glad i have control again")
#time.sleep(5)
print ("so much control")
###
#time.sleep(1)
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
###
code1 = input("1 ")

if code1 != ("5648"):
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(1)
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print ("wrong")
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print ("wrong")

    incorrectguess = ("1")
    destroyapp()

code2 = input("2 ")
code3 = input("3 ")
code4 = input("4 ")

else:
    destroyapp()
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
 RESTART: C:/Users/Harvey (New)/Desktop/CARTER/program (destroy on wrong code).py
```

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Harvey (New)/Desktop/CARTER/program (destroy on wrong code).py", line 4, in <module>
    if incorrectguess == ("1"):
NameError: name 'incorrectguess' is not defined`

Comment: Could you please show us your code?

Comment: We can't help you much without seeing the code that you tried.

Comment: What's `destroyapp`?

Comment: programmers work with code, not with pictures.

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. Don't post images of code or error messages. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: In case, it wasn't obvious, I'm absolutely clueless right now I can't get anything to work... Anything else you need, please let me know and I'll try to get it on.

Comment: Well, you need to define `incorrectguess` ???

Comment: And that's what I'm clueless about. I'm literally at the very basics right now

Comment: What you have done is said if `incorrectguess` is equal to one, do something. Your program, however, hasn't been told what `incorrectguess` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# consider 1 as the correct password and 0 as incorrect

Is_guess_correct = -1

password = ("secret")

password_guess = input("guess my password")

while password_guess != password:
    print("wrong")
    Is_guess_correct = 0
    password_guess = input("guess my password")
Is_guess_correct = 1
```